# Conflict between htaccess .php and .jpeg

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a directory called api with an .htaccess that adds .php to every file in it.

```
# Turn on the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine  on
# If the request doesn't end in .php (Case insensitive) continue processing 
rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
# If the request doesn't end in a slash continue processing the rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
# Rewrite the request with a .php extension. L means this is the 'Last' rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

As you can see I have copy pasted it and now I have no idea how to fix following problem:

> I have a directory called data in it that contains media, thus every media file is called **{something}.{mp3/jpeg/mov}.php** once i request it.

Is there any way I can fix this, for example by overriding the rule in my */data/* directory?

**EDIT**

```
# Turn on the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine  on
# If the request doesn't end in .php (Case insensitive) continue processing 
rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
# If the request doesn't end in a slash continue processing the rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Rewrite the request with a .php extension. L means this is the 'Last' rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: You could add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`. This will only continue processing if the file does not exist.

Comment: Where should I put it?

Comment: You can put it the line before `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]`

Comment: I get following error message: **The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.** The new code is in the edit

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. `RewriteCond ` needs to be in front of it. Its condition just like the 2 you already have.

Comment: Wow, it worked, I cant thank you enough!!!